# Ambiguous occurrence ‘product’

Tags: haskell

**Code:**

```
product :: (Eq p, Num p) => p -> p
product 1 = 1
product n = n * product (n-1)
```

**Usage:**

```
main = print (product(8))
```

**Error:**

```
GHCi, version 8.10.6: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/runner/University-Labs/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )

Main.hs:3:17: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘product’
    It could refer to
       either ‘Prelude.product’,
              imported from ‘Prelude’ at Main.hs:1:1
              (and originally defined in ‘Data.Foldable’)
           or ‘Main.product’, defined at Main.hs:2:1
  |
3 | product n = n * product (n-1)
  |                 ^^^^^^^

Main.hs:5:15: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘product’
    It could refer to
       either ‘Prelude.product’,
              imported from ‘Prelude’ at Main.hs:1:1
              (and originally defined in ‘Data.Foldable’)
           or ‘Main.product’, defined at Main.hs:2:1
  |
5 | main = print (product(8))
  |               ^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
 
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: main
    • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
 ^
```

Comment: You have two functions named `product`, one defined in `Prelude` (an implicitly imported module) and one defined in the `Main` module defined by your code. The compiler doesn't know which one a bare word `product` is supposed to refer to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a function called [`product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:product) in the `Prelude` which is imported by default. So you have two functions named `product`: The one you wrote and the one built-in to Haskell.

You can always change your function's name. The function you've written there is typically called the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial), so you could change the name to that.

You can also refer to your function by its fully qualified name.

```
main = print (Main.product 8)
```

(Note that modules not given an explicit name in Haskell are assumed to be named `Main`, so it's as though your file started with `module Main where`)

Alternatively, you can explicitly import the `Prelude` and hide what you don't want.

```
import Prelude hiding (product)
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize `hiding` worked if the module had already been imported. I didn't answer because I didn't want to get into how to disable the implicit Prelude import.

Comment: @chepner It only works for `Prelude`. If your module contains an import for `Prelude`, then the implicit `Prelude` import that applies to all modules is disabled, and the one you wrote yourself is the *only* import for `Prelude`.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.